# Salesforce iOS Chat disappears with iOS 13

Tags: xcode, ios13, salesforce-ios-sdk

I am using the Salesforce iOS SDK for Customer Support (https://github.com/forcedotcom/ServiceSDK-iOS). With the update to iOS 13 the view disappears right after showing. I cannot edit the code so I have to ask if someone has the same problem and worked out some workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I'm in the same boat.

Here's an [official statement](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003eoAQAQ) from Salesforce saying that a new SDK should be available starting October 7.

There was a [discussion about this on GitHub](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?client=safari&sxsrf=ACYBGNS3IP2oMCj-gDCMem83dGg0C8y3UQ%3A1570016571824&ei=O42UXar1MZHzkwXnhaGwBQ&q=cache%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fforcedotcom%2FServiceSDK-iOS%2Fissues%2F106&oq=cache%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fforcedotcom%2FServiceSDK-iOS%2Fissues%2F106&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1204.1204..1397...0.2..0.70.70.1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.YqPNpRrwvRo&ved=0ahUKEwjq_rfAv_3kAhWR-aQKHedCCFYQ4dUDCAo&uact=5) also, but they've removed issues from their repo recently.

I guess we'll just have to wait until next week.